# Convert utf-8 file name to readable string

Tags: java, string

I have a file with name from an email attachment called:

`=?UTF-8?Q?20._=D0=96=D0=B5=D1=80=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=BC_(feat._Heaven).mp3?=`

How can I convert it to a readable cyrillic string?

Comment: Like you just have the file on your computer? Or you've downloading in a java program somehow and need to rename it? It's unclear what you're needing to do.

Comment: that's doesn't really matters, Darren

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, are you trying to rename a file?